# running a query from C# on sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

when i run a query like this:

```
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from some table", myConnection);
```

before doing the select, should i be doing `"use somedatabase; go"` ??

Comment: That is specified in your connection string.

Comment: You can see what connection string is appropriate for your scenario by going to http://connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your database and schema should be set in the connection string for `myConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

No you should specify the database name in myConnection

```
InitialCatalog = [databaseName]
```

Your connection string should something look like this

```
data source=[ServerName];Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine `myConnection` is already specifying a default catalog (i.e. database) in its connection string, so you don't need to use the `use` line.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

No; the myConnection object's connection string should define which database needs to be used, along with the server and login information.

Answer (score 0):

That should all be in the myConnection variable, since I presume that contains the connection string.

Although you might want to call using on the DataAdapter

```
using(SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from some table", myConnection)
{
    //do stuff with dap here 
}//dispose of dap
```

Since it does inherit from something that implements IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string tells it what database to connect to.

```
connectionString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

That would create a connection to a server and database using windows authentication.